# bootstrap 3 - grid and functionality not rendering properly in ie11/windows 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Page in question: http://ikonltd.com/current/

Page looks perfect in ff and  chrome.

Check it in IE11 on desktop/laptop at full width (i'm running windows 8 but guessing that doesn't make a difference in this case). This also displays the exact same way in windows/Safari -although I know bootstrap doesn't support windows/Safari.

I'm using these:

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ikonltd.com/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

No luck. I've tested the code and removed, one by one, each javascript and css script and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: First time using this interface. The proper URL is: http://ikonltd.com/current/. I'm already using these recommended ie fixes: <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ikonltd.com/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

Comment: Check your developers console man...

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Well, as is often the case, it was an over site on my part.

One of my media queries was missing a closing bracket!!!!!

Comment: Always make sure your code is valid to avoid such mistakes in the future, goodl luck!